# MathJax on Android browsers

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, mathjax

I want to write some math notes on my website, but I am in trouble with MathJax. MathJax equations are good on PC, but they are very small on browsers for Android.

I have used the following code [on this webpage](http://matefis.altervista.org/example.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    \[ i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = \hat{H}\Psi \]
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \( f_x(x,y,z) \) 
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet 
    nec ullamcorper sit. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue 
    eget arcu. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Tortor aliquam 
    nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Adipiscing elit pellentesque 
    habitant morbi tristique. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
    fames.</p>
</body>
```

It looks good on PC, but it doesn't look good on mobile browsers. MathJax equations are smaller than text, as you can see [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L48kJ.png). Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Adding that line it seems solved